# how to use local notifications in phone gap?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, phonegap

Hello every one I'm beginner in phonegap

i wanna use mobile local notifications and searched alot for plugins

used phone gap local notifications and other plugins , unfortunately all not working

now i'm trying cordova plugin

this is my js  code

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    alert('1');
    cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
        title: 'My first notification',
        text: 'Thats pretty easy...',
        foreground: true
    });
    alert('2')
}
```

html

scripts

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
```

config.xml

```
 <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer2" spec="^1.0.1" />
    <plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" spec="^2.1.2">
        <variable name="FCM_VERSION" value="11.0.1" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="phonegap-plugin-local-notification" spec="^1.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-local-notification" spec="^0.9.0-beta.2" />
    <gap:plugin name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification" />
```

first alert appear but second not appear

what should i do to achieve that

thanks every one

Comment: that is the plugin i try to use :: https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code.

In your config.xml

```
 <plugin spec=" https://github.com/acianti/cordova-plugin-local-notifications.git" />
```

this is the script code

```
   var alarmTime = new Date();

   alarmTime.setMinutes(alarmTime.getMinutes() + 1);

cordova.plugins.notification.local.registerPermission(function (str) {


   cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
    id: '1',
    title: 'Test Notification',
    message: 'Hello',
    date: alarmTime
    });
});
```